# Enable selectBox after selecting another one

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json

I trying to set two `select-boxes` to work by enabling the second select-box after choosing an option from the first.

The results comes from a json with js to a div on my page.

The 2nd select is set to `disabled`

First try:

**JavaScript:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.getJSON('./system/feeds/built.search.php', function (json) {
        var output = '';
        output += '<div class="search_block">';
        output += '<h2><img src="images/search_icon_big.png" alt=""> Search used cars</h2>';
        output += '<form id="form1" class="form-style" method="post">';
        output += '<label><strong>Company</strong><br>';
        output += '<span class="select1">';
        output += '<select name="companies" id="companies">';
        output += '<option>All</option>';
        output += '<option value="company">Company</option>';
        for (var i = 0; i < json.company_models.length; i++) {
            output += '<option value=' + json.company_models[i].company + '>' + json.company_models[i].company + '</option>';
        }
        output += '</select>';
        output += '</span>';
        output += '</label>';
        output += '<label><strong>Model</strong><br>';
        output += '<span class="select1">';
        output += '<select name="models" id="models" disabled>';
        output += '<option>Choose Company</option>';
        $('#companies').change(function () {
            if (this.value) {
                document.getElementById('#models').disabled = true;
            } else {
                document.getElementById('#models').disabled = false;
            }
        });
        for (i = 0; i < json.company_models.length; i++) {
            output += '<option value=' + json.company_models[i].model + '>' + json.company_models[i].model + '</option>';
        }
        output += '</select>';
        output += '</span>';
        output += '</label>';
        $('#search').html(output);
    });
});
```

**HTML**:

```
<div id="search" class="grid_12"></div>
```

[jsfiddle.net/mJdmQ](http://jsfiddle.net/mJdmQ)

To make it more easy:

`Company | Model`: *To choose the options from **Model** i must choose first an option from **Company***

**PS:** To save you sometime referring about similar questions, I already looked them...

Comment: Always include your code in the question. There's no guarantee linked code will be available indefinitely, so all relevant parts of the code should be included. I'm surprise you were even able to do post that link. I could have sworn links to jsfiddle are  disallowed in questions without code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for a `.change()` event with jQuery (`onchange` in pure js), and since this is dynamically loaded data, you'll need to use `.on()`:

```
$(document).on("change", "#companies", function() {
    this.value == "All" ? $("#models").prop("disabled", true) : $("#models").prop("disabled", false);
});
```

Comment: Already check them as i mentioned. I tried your opinion and its not working. The strange think is that there is no error. It just not working

Comment: @JohnPriestakos -- Ahh woops, it dynamic data, one second

Comment: @JohnPriestakos -- Give it a try now.

Comment: YES. At last. Thank you @tymeJV. I'll check it now, thank to you, on how to disable it again if the `<option>All</option>` is selected again.

Comment: @JohnPriestakos - Simple ternary statement, I updated the answer with that functionality

Comment: Thank you @tymeJV. Works like charm

Comment: You could potentially avoid some of that typing (albeit you might have to cache the `this` first): `$("#models").prop("disabled", this.value == 'All');`